Android studio debugger not stopping on breakpoints in submodules in flutter project
So I have this flutter project that consists of 3 git repositories, 1 main repository and 2 submodules. the submodules are connected via symbolic links. I used to use Android Studio for developing, one day for no apparent reason the debugger stopped working in submodules, meaning that if I have a breakpoint in the main repository (the entry to the project) the debugger will stop when reaching that point, however, when the breakpoint is inside any of the submodules the debugger will simply skip the breakpoint and the icon of the breakpoint will turn from solid red to a red circle with an x in it. I switched to using visual studio code and the debugger works fine inside the submodules. I remember when I searched once that there was a file in the project that has some settings regarding the submodules, I tired to play with it but with no luck. Is there anyone who faced such a problem ? please help because I really dont like visual studio code for flutter development.
I tried updating android studio to the latest version but with no luck

Not a git question

I think its related to the git submodule behavior with the IDE
